# Event and EventHandle in Dart

Tags: dart, events, event-handling

I'm coming from C# and I understand (more or less) the logic around the Events and how they works. Now, I have to traduce an event paradigm (with data passing) from C# to Dart but I don't understand how it works on Dart. Can anyone explain to me patiently? Thanks

EDIT: These are the pieces of code that i have to translate

`Class Engine.cs`

```cs
public class Engine {
    [...]
    public event EventHandler<EngineComputationEventArgs> ComputationCompleted;

     protected virtual void OnComputationCompleted(Result result) {
         var evt = ComputationCompleted;
         if (evt != null) {
             evt(this, new EngineComputationEventArgs(result));
         }
     }
}
```

`Class Example.cs`

```cs
[...]

engine.ComputationCompleted += (sender, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("PPE {0}", e.Result.Ppe);
};

[...]
```

and `EngineComputationEventArgs.cs`

```cs
public class EngineComputationEventArgs : EventArgs {

    public EngineComputationEventArgs(Result result) {
        Result = result;
    }

    public Result Result { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide some pseudo code which shows what your problem is? I don't really understand what you are looking for.  Are we talking about some description of what `Future` and `Stream` are in Dart?

Comment: I edited the post with the code which I have to translate but making it short yes, I would like understand how how Future and Stream works in Dart (I think that I need use one of them for the translation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart does not have built in "Event" types like C# does. You usually use a `Stream` as event emitter, and a corresponding `StreamController` to add events to it.

Example:

```dart
class Engine {
  final StreamController<EngineComputationEventArgs> _computationCompleted =
     StreamController.broadcast(/*sync: true*/);

  Stream<EngineComputationEventArgs> get computationCompleted => 
      _computationCompleted.stream;

  void onComputationCompleted(Result result) {
    if (_computationCompleted.hasListener) {
      _computationCompleted.add(EngineComputationEventArgs(result));
    }
  }
}
```

You then add listeners by listening on the stream:

```dart
engine.computationCompleted.forEach((e) =>
    print("PPE ${e.result.ppe}"));
```

or

```dart
var subscription = engine.computationCompleted.listen((e) =>
    print("PPE ${e.result.ppe}"));
// Can call `subscription.cancel()` later to stop listening.
```

Your "args" class could be (since I know nothing about `EventArgs`)

```dart
class EngineComputationEventArgs extends EventArgs {
  final Result result;
 
  EngineComputationEventArgs(this.result);
}
```

Comment: The solution works... Can you also explain me the differences between `Stream` and `Future` and why I should use one than the other

Comment: I recommend reading [Futures](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) in the language tutorials.